# The same SQL but have different result

Tags: mysql, sql

ps:the description show detail with the href: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000014649728
I run the follow sql :

```
select *  from
(
    select *,(@num2 := 
    (if(@GROUP199=`C_ISHOT`,@num2+1,if(@GROUP199:=`C_ISHOT`,1,1)))) row_number
    from city_code order by C_ISHOT 
) result
    where row_number<=10
```

the first run result show the table total numbers,
but the second run result is my expected。 what's the matter with it,and how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

The variables are not initialized.

```
select * 
from ( select *, (@num2 :=(if(@GROUP199=C_ISHOT,@num2+1,if(@GROUP199:=C_ISHOT,1,1)))) row_number 
       from city_code, ( SELECT @num2 := 0, @GROUP199 := 0 ) init_vars
       order by C_ISHOT ) result 
where row_number<=10
```